# SonarQube 6.7: how do no-admin users create a project?

Tags: sonarqube

I have just installed SonarQube 6.7 and I am creating users for my colleagues, who would like to create a project from their source code hosted on GitHub repositories.

So far I did not find a way to let users create a project, without setting them as system administrator. Apparently a project is created indeed from the *Create Project* button on the **Administration > Projects > Management** page as reported in the official [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Existence).

Unfortunately in this way, most users should be set as admin if they want to create projects: therefore they will be able to manage the users and the whole system. As you can imagine it is not ideal situation, when a lot of administrators on a system.

How can users be able to create a project without having admin privileges over the whole system (configuration, security, users, etc.)?

I thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your users need the [Create Projects](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization#Authorization-GlobalPermissions) global permission. You can grant this individually or by putting them in a group and giving the group the permission.

They'll need the Execute Analysis global permission as well (another argument for using a group). Once these permissions are granted, they'll be able to analyze projects. Any project that doesn't already exist will be created in SonarQube on the first analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Vittorio C. I have the same issue as you in the SonarQube 6.7.

Issue: few options will not show up for example "create projects under global permissions"

Resolution: Just search the "create user"s in the search window( shown in the screenshot) and it will start appearing.

[image: screen shot]

Also if you think any option is not appearing but which ideally should, you can apply the same trick.

Answer (score 0):

for example with maven, `mvn package sonar:sonar` will create project if no exist in sonarqube. 
If you want to create it before first use you can use web api, for example have a look at https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/projects/create 
 If i'm not wrong the create API is open to everyone.